# Where to initialize reference type dependency properties for a custom control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a custom control with dependency properties.  I know that if a dependency property is a reference type, I need to initialize it in each instance of the control or else they all use the same object.  In normal controls, I do this in the constructor.  But in my custom control, where do I do this?  OnApplyTemplate() method?

Comment: Do you have a code sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is the solution: http://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/blog/2010/02/11/be-careful-with-default-values-of-dependency-properties-if-youre-using-reference-types/

You can have both a static constructor and an instance constructor for your custom control.  Initialize the reference type dependency properties inside of the instance constructor.

Comment: constructor always initializes properties and value types even you didn't write your property or value type in the constructor like in my answer:)

Answer (score 0):

`DependencyProperty` can be created in a traditional way like at any classes where you declare `DependencyProperty`. There is no special rules to declare dependency property in `CustomControl`.

```
public class YourCustomControl : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TestPropProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("TestProp", typeof(string), typeof(TestControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public string TestProp
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TestPropProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TestPropProperty, value); }
    }

    static YourCustomControl()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(TestControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(TestControl)));
    }
}
```